# react-hooks/exhaustive-deps warning or infinite loop?

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I have a `mediaType` variable, when it change, `currentSelectedMedia` need to be filtered. In this scenario, I get `react-hooks/exhaustive-deps` warning.

```
  /**
  data example:

  currentSelectedMedia = [
    { id: '1', mediaType: '1', name: 'facebook'},
    { id: '2', mediaType: '2', name: 'twitter'}
  ]
  **/

  useEffect(() => {
    setCurrentSelectedMedia(currentSelectedMedia.filter(item => item.mediaType === mediaType))
  }, [mediaType])
```

If I add `currentSelectedMedia` to the dependency array，infinite loop is caused.

the warning is right according to the rule, the reason of infinite loop is also obvious.
But how can I get escape?

Comment: Why do you want `currentSelectedMedia` in the dependency list? What are you trying to achieve by doing so? Think we'll need more context.

Comment: Can you post what can be the value of `id` and what data does `mediaDataMap` contains?

Comment: @Jayce444  I want avoid the warning, `react-hooks/exhaustive-deps`

Comment: @Yadab I edit the example, do not care `mediaDataMap`, it's irrelative

Comment: Just render the content using `currentSelectedMedia.filter(item => item.mediaType === mediaType)` you really don't need to use useEffect as you are calling it whenever `mediaType` changes

Answer (score 1):

You are getting react-hooks/exhaustive-deps warning or infinite loop because your `useEffect` hook gets trigger every time there is a change in `mediaType` state;
And in your `useEffect` method you are setting the value of `mediaType` state;

To solve this problem either you can have two different state or just a normal function which sets the `mediaType` or just create a variable which filters the data when your state gets change.
That depends on how you are setting your mediaType state from other places.

```
const filteredData = currentSelectedMedia.filter(item => item.mediaType === mediaType);
```

Use filteredData to render the data.

Comment: filteredMedia has to be a state variable, it can be modified by other logic and should cause re-render

Comment: It will cause re-render because your `mediaType` variable is state variable.

Answer (score 1):

I believe what you want is getting the filtered selected media.

However, using useEffect in this instance may not be the most appropriate. You may want to consider **useMemo** instead.

```
const filteredMedia = useMemo(() => {
    return currentSelectedMedia.filter(item => item.mediaType === mediaType)
}, [currentSelectedMedia, mediaType] )
```

You may then use `filteredMedia` in your rendering.

The value will only be *re-filtered* when `currentSelectedMedia` or `mediaType` changed.

The above is almost equivalent to

```
 const filteredMedia = currentSelectedMedia.filter(item => item.mediaType === mediaType)
```

The difference is - useMemo is "memorized", so it won't be recalculated on every render.

Small performance difference for small arrays and calculation, visible performance boost when you are handling huge list and complicated calculations.

Comment: I +1 this answer because useMemo will definitely work, but useMemo is most efficient when storing complex calculations. The performance cost outweighs the functionality benefit in this case.

Comment: but in my case, filteredMedia has to be a state variable, it can be modified by other logic and should cause re-render, I will give a complete demo later.

Comment: You can modify any states, and any logics, just add the states in the dependency list. Treat useMemo like a "cocktail of states". You can manage many independent simple states of (values) and use useMemo to combine all these values into something that you can use in render.

Answer (score 0):

`useEffect` will trigger on mount and each time one of it's dependencies change. If you add `currentSelectedMedia` to it's dependency list and you are also modifying `currentSelectedMedia` within your `useEffect` causing the **infinite loop.**

I would simply use the same logic that would change `mediaType` (most likely an `[action]Handler` function) and `setCurrentSelectedMedia` there.